# How to resize a verified PayPal image based on screen size

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, paypal

I have copied the following code from PayPals website from [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/logo-center):

```
<!-- PayPal Logo --><table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td 
align="center"></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal- 
popup" title="How PayPal Works" 
onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal- 
popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, 
resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/AM_SbyPP_mc_vs_dc_ae.jpg" border="0" 
alt="PayPal Acceptance Mark"></a></td></tr></table><!-- PayPal Logo -->
```

Here, I assigned a div class ("payment-secure-logo") to the code which gives:

```
<div class="payment-secure-logo">
<!-- PayPal Logo --><table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td 
align="center"></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal- 
popup" title="How PayPal Works" 
onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal- 
popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, 
resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img src="Images/paypal-visa-mc-logos- 
500px.png" border="0" alt="PayPal Acceptance Mark"></a></td></tr></table><!-- PayPal Logo -->
</div>
```

From this point I add the following css styling:

```
.payment-secure-logo {
display: block;
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
}
```

This code works by showing the image and redirecting to paypal when clicked.
 Unfortunately I am unable to resize or move the image.

My goal is to have the image scale in size based on screen size, when I view the image in mobile it clips outside of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Below Snippet. Hope it helps.

```css
.payment-secure-logo {
display: block;
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
}

.payment-secure-logo table img{width:100%}
```

```html
<div class="payment-secure-logo">
<!-- PayPal Logo --><table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td 
align="center"></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal- 
popup" title="How PayPal Works" 
onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal- 
popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, 
resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/AM_SbyPP_mc_vs_dc_ae.jpg" border="0" alt="PayPal Acceptance Mark"></a></td></tr></table><!-- PayPal Logo -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your div's size when the viewport goes below a certain width:

```
.payment-secure-logo {
        display: block;
        width: 30vw;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 300px;
        max-height: 300px;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .payment-secure-logo {
        width: 80vw;
    }
}
```